# Is Hibernate changing '0' value to 'NULL'?

Tags: c#, sql-server, hibernate

I have inherited an application to perform some bug fixes. The language is C# and it uses Hibernate to communicate with a SQL Server 2016 database.

I have one table with "Types of Element"  that it looks like this:
- 0: Type A
- 1: Type B
- 2: Type C

The table "Element" has a field for the type. That field is "int NOT NULL" with a Foregin Key to the other table.

If I try to insert an element with "Type = 0", Hibernate throws this error:

```
not-null property references a null or transient value
```

If I check the log written in the console by Hibernate, I see that it is trying to insert NULL value for that field:

```
@p27 = NULL [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Any other value of "Type" works fine.

It is my first time with Hibernate and I can't find any solution for a .NET application.

The mapping of the "Type" table:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="aaa"
               namespace="aaa">
<class name="Type" table="Type">
<id name="COD" column="COD">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="DESC" column="DESC" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The other one:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="aaa"
               namespace="aaa">
<class name="Element" table="Elements">
<id name="COD" column="COD">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="Type" column="Type" />
<property name="DESC" column="DESC" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: I looked at the hibernate schema on the web.  I think the type should be lowercase 't' instead of uppercase.  I hoping this is the issue.  A lot of items are defined i the schema as positiveInteger and hopefully that includes zero.

Comment: Are you trying to access the data by the index number in the array, or the key?  Looks like index zero may be null.  See : https://www.intertech.com/Blog/hibernate-why-are-there-nulls-in-my-collection/  You may need to reference by the key.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll test what you have posted